# jQuery Fade transient element

Tags: jquery

I have a page where some `div` appear if someting happens. Usually, those `div` are transient status messages.

I would like that those messages disappear after some delay.
I tried

```
<div id="result-messages"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  // fade out flash 'success' messages
  $('.transient-warn-message').delay(1000).fadeTo(1000,0,function(){$(this).html('');});
});
</script>
```

If the `div` with `id="result-message"` will contain an inner `<div class="transient-warn-message">`, it will not disappear...

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d4cWL/1/

Comment: Try to add the warn message later in time...

Comment: your code does not handle that scenario, can you call a method once you add that element which will execute `$('.transient-warn-message').delay(1000).fadeTo(1000,0,function(){$(this).html('');});` again

Comment: ..and in fact I would like to handle it...that the question!

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d4cWL/4/ - [supports only modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: look at mutation events for IE9+ support

Comment: @Arun: it is good, please make an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) for this - [supports only modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Browser_compatibility)

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    function warnOut() {
        if ($('#result-messages .transient-warn-message').length) {
            // fade out flash 'success' messages
            $('.transient-warn-message').delay(1000).fadeTo(1000, 0, function () {
                $(this).html('');
            });
        }
    }

    warnOut();


    // select the target node
    var target = document.querySelector('#result-messages');

    // create an observer instance
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
        if ($('#result-messages .transient-warn-message').length) {
            warnOut();
        }
    });

    // configuration of the observer:
    var config = {
        attributes: true,
        childList: true,
        characterData: true
    };

    // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
    observer.observe(target, config);

    // later, you can stop observing
    //observer.disconnect();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d4cWL/)